# How to detect when object it is on-screen? bge

Tags: game-engine

I was wondering if it is possible to detect an object when is on-screen/visible to the camera? This feature should NOT detect an object when it's behind another object.

I highly doubt this question has been asked before. Please help...

Comment: This is not that easy. It is possible to measure if an object is within the camera frustum, but it does not care if the object is covered by another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough from python by casting a ray from the camera to the object:

```
import bge
own = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
cam = own.scene.active_camera
own_screen_pos = cam.getScreenPosition(own)
result = cam.getScreenRay(*own_screen_pos, 100)
if result == own:
    print("The object can be seen")
else:
    print("The object cannot be seen")
```

Be aware this will only check the centerpoint of the object rather than the edges.